# Service Worker - why do all definitions of addEventListeners ignore after first evaluation of script?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I read some articles and issues about that, but still can't understand motivation of such way using.

This sw will ignore listener:

```
(async () => {
  await new Promise(handler => setTimeout(() => handler(), 0));
  console.log("await");
  self.addEventListener('message', (e) => console.log(e))
})()
```

also you will get a warn with such words:

> Event handler of 'message' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script.

---

But this sw won't ignore a listener:

```
self.addEventListener('message', (e) => console.log(e))
```

Why will "deferred" addEventListeners be ignored?

Answer (score 0):

In a service worker, the `message` event is used to communicate with the worker from the main thread, and **it is possible for messages to be sent to the worker before the worker has finished initializing**. In this case, any `addEventListener()` calls for the message event that are made after the worker is started will be ignored.

To avoid this issue, the `addEventListener()` call for the message event should be made before the worker is fully initialized so that it is guaranteed to catch any messages that are sent to the worker.

Comment: You say that: "any addEventListener() calls for the message event that are made after the worker is started will be ignored" - because some messages might be missed, is it? But who cares whether missed or not our messages. I don't understand.

So in SW style, addEventListener added to a normal script should also not work due to the fact that some events can be lost. But this is nonsense.

Comment: What I meant was  "deferred" `addEventListeners` in a Service Worker might be ignored due to how the browser evaluates the worker script. When a Service Worker script is first loaded, the browser will immediately evaluate it and any code that is outside of a function will be executed. In your case, the code that adds the event listener is inside an immediately-invoked async function expression. This means that the function containing the `addEventListener` will not be executed until after the Promise is resolved, which is after the initial evaluation of the worker script.